# Retrieve extreme ray for infeasible linear program from CPLEX in Pyomo

Tags: cplex, pyomo

Is there a way to retrieve unbounded rays when the linear program is feasible and its dual problem is unbounded from CPLEX interfaced with Pyomo?

What is assured is: 1) from CPLEX interfaced with Pyomo, dual values can be retrieved if the problem is feasible, and 2) using CPLEX class in the Python API
the unbounded rays are retrievable via functions like `get_ray` and `get_dual_values`.

Comment: If you do a grep on the Pyomo package, you will see that `get_ray` is not found. It appears that Pyomo does not support this. As you say, if you use the CPLEX Python API directly, it is supported.

Comment: It looks like this question was also asked [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/zMyKXFGeaS4) on the Pyomo forum.

Comment: Thanks, @rkersh.